# Instagram API Comments Endpoint Returning Non-unique IDs

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

About an hour ago (2016-04-07 21:00:00 UTC) the /media/media-id/comments endpoint started to return non-unique identifiers for comments. Existing comments were assigned a new ID and the old comment IDs no longer work.

Has anyone seen official documentation about an expected ID migration as part of the new API changes? I see no announcements or developer documentation about new IDs.

Comment: Yesterday I submitted a bug report to Instagram via their developer site. If anyone else is experiencing this issue, please fill out a report. It will help bring attention of this issue to Instagram. Directions for submitting a bug report can be found on this page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, but when doing the same API call now, the API is returning the old IDs again. So maybe a temporary hick-up?!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still seeing wrong IDs returned. The frequency seems to have been reduced, but it's still happening. I'm beginning to suspect there is a bad server that their load balancer occasionally points to.

Comment: Correction, the issue has been fixed. I was purging the newest duplicates from the database, which was fine for all comments but the ones created during the issue time. Comments created during the issue time were first captured with the wrong id, and the second (newest) capture had the correct id. By deleting the newest version of the comments, I was deleting some comments with correct IDs, and they would be recaptured again when fetching from the API. Once I purged all incorrect IDs from the database, I am no longer seeing this issue.